# Get IndexOf an Array Element without IndexOf or Loops

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, recursion, tail-recursion

I've got the following task:
My program should calculate the lowest number from an array in a recursive way.
My program should look like this:

```
public static double minimumRekursiv(double []array, int startposition, int endposition){
}
```

And with the following input:

```
double [] array = {0.1,0.3,-0.6,-1,.99};
System.out.println(minimumRekursiv(array,0,array.length-1));
```

The Output should be `-1.0`

**I am not allowed to use any loops or packages except for** `.math` **(sadly)**

I got the following instructions:

1. if startposition == endposition return array[startposition]
2. else: calculate the average between startposition and endposition
3. calculate the minimum for the first half from startposition to average by using the method "minimumRekursiv" again
4. calculate the minimum for the first half from average+1 to endposition by using the method "minimumRekursiv" again
5. return the minimum between the minima of both halves

I've followed steps 1-4 but don't know how to access the positions of the minima of each half. I'm used to the array.IndexOf function which I am not allowed to use. Did I make any "bigger" mistakes or is there a simple solution that I'm missing?

```
public static double minimumRekursiv(double []array, int startposition, int endposition){
    if (startposition == endposition){
        return array[startposition];
    }
    double a;
    a = (startposition+endposition)/2;

    int average = (int) a;
    double minimumerstehälfte;
    double mimimumzweitehälfte;

    minimumerstehälfte = minimumRekursiv(array, startposition, average);

    mimimumzweitehälfte = minimumRekursiv(array, average+1, endposition);

    //Here it goes wrong / I am not allowed to use index of 
    return minimumRekursiv(array, indexOf(array, minimumerstehälfte), indexOf(array, mimimumzweitehälfte));

}
```

Comment: What is the goal of `return minimumRekursiv(array, indexOf(array, minimumerstehälfte), indexOf(array, mimimumzweitehälfte));`? At no point do you compare array values, so how can you be computing the minimum?

Comment: Step 5 is much simpler than you think -- you already have the minima from the two halves -- you just need to return the smallest.

Comment: Thank you davies, no clue why i didnt get this myself.